# What in the shells is this puzzle?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

> Clergyman's wife tells story of pick*ing* up a muscle.

<sup>Solution: $\require{color}\definecolor{hint}{RGB}{1,124,233} \small\color{hint}{\textsf{5 words}}$</sup>

Comment: Are you sure you mean muscle and not mussel?

Comment: @benzene Quite sure.

Comment: Making me think of she sells sea shells along the sea shore

Comment: Is it about Socrates's wife called Xanthappe's quarrelsome attitude leading to heated vocal conversation @Rubio ?!

Comment: When you solve it, *you'll know* you've solved it (though a fifth word may escape you; you'll probably eventually find it where you didn't quite expect to).  [@MeaCulpaNay]

Comment: I think I've seen all the components of solving this, other than the actual 5 words themselves, correctly guessed at by people contemplating this puzzle in The Sphinx's Lair.  Of course I won't say which guesses were right and which were wrong, but given that the right guesses have been made, *how* the puzzle works is within potential solvers' grasp. Without further comment, I'll note that most (all?) the commentary in TSL about this puzzle can be found at/near the relevant looking hits on [this search](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=shells&room=14524).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the title:

> The word that jumps out the most is "shells". My first thought was that this might mean that we need to find synonyms and only take the outer/inner letters, but this didn't lead me anywhere. Later in The Sphinx's Lair @Alconja suggested that maybe "shells" means the words could be arranged in a matryoshka doll-like pattern, i.e. A(B(C(D)E)F)G, which I thought was a really good idea.

From the hint:

> The color of "5 words" is 0x17ce9 = 97513, which I think gives the length of each of our 5 words in order.

Putting this together:

> Clergyman's wife tells story of picking up **a** muscle.
>   **a**
>
>   Clergyman's wife tells story of picking up a **muscle**.
>  **l**a**t**
>
>   Clergyman's wife tells story of **picking up** a muscle.
>   **e**lat**e**
>
>   Clergyman's wife **tells story** of picking up a muscle.
>   **r**elate**s**
>
>   **Clergyman's wife** tells story of picking up a muscle.
>   **p**relates**s**

Comment: Good job! What was the relevance of pick*ing*?

Comment: @DavidFoong it's there to indicate that the verb tense doesn't match with the answer.

Comment: Nicely done!  And yes - the *ing* was italicized to indicate it was just there for surface reading, as guessed by [@Sp3000](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39254496#39254496)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> **A Story of Two Lives**,
>  a chapter in the book *Miss Margaret's Stories, By A Clergyman's Wife, Author Of 'katie's Counsel'*? It talks about an orphan boy who works with a spade in the garden, who told the stories about Miss Margaret, a clergyman's wife.

I'm not so sure if this is the intended solution though, since I didn't get the shell reference in the title and I don't understand how fifth word may escape me. Also I don't understand why '*ing*' in 'picking' is italicized.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the solution.  The title is an important clue to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I decided to

> Take the sentence and look for alternate meanings.

To start off,

> I took Clergeyman's wife and turned it into Presbytera (I know, technically that's a **preacher's** wife). Then, I took "tells story" and changed it to "preach(es/ed)" in order to keep with the religious theme. Next, I gave up because I couldn't fit the rest of it. That leaves us with Presbytera preaches *[word]* *[word]* *[word]*

Thoughts:

> I'm hoping this is along the right track. It seems to me like this is the right way to solve it, especially with the *wordplay* tag attached to the puzzle. Pick*ing* makes no sense to me. Maybe it's supposed to separate the word?

Answer (score -1):

It's just a guess, but it seems

> "pickING up a muscle" might tell us to literally pick ING up MUSCLE (...which leads us to MUSING-CLE)???

Comment: To quote from the puzzle: "Solution: 5 words"