# What in the hell is for dinner?

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

The telegram service is so bad these days! You can't trust them to convey a message safely without missing some of the letters or even mis-spacing words. Here's the nonsense you got today:

> Hi! Re Ada O.A. Regan, error-is as in scap-he.

And all you wanted to know was what's for dinner. Unless ... maybe your puzzling friend is playing a trick on you and making you blame the telegram service for her cryptic message?

**So, what *is* for dinner?**

Comment: Inspired by an incorrect guess at the solution of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/54059/5373).

Comment: Well, I haven't solved all of it, but it starts 'Hi reader...'

Comment: I don't suppose the answer is mussels :). I looked up [scaphe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaphe), and it's an ancient sundial. It also means bowl. I'm not sure how relevant that info is, but looking at sundial error led me nowhere.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil the left side can make:

Hi reader a ago an

Although I'm not really sure what to do with that. The right side doesn't have the same format so I'm assuming you do something to the left side with the right side's info

Comment: @DavidFoong not sure about the right side, the end of scaphe could sort of make 'cafe'

Comment: Possibly on the wrong track, but I read the first part as "Hire a", and if you take O. as ---., that can become M (--) and N(-.), so the sentence starts with "Hire a damn", possibly saying something like "Hire a damn maid to get your dinner". I can't get the rest of the sentence to work though.

Comment: How concerned should we be with punctuation?

Comment: @feelinferrety Not at all.

Comment: I don't think the anagram path is right. @Alpha has probably got the right idea. The two main ways you could interpret the beginning are "Hire a..."
 and "Hi! Read a...". Rand al said we shouldn't worry about punctuation, so I guess O.A. isn't short for something. I'm still completely unsure of what the right side is pointing to. Looking up scaphe got me nowhere.

Comment: To clarify my above comment (since I've been told it was confusing), this puzzle was inspired by *my own, unspoken* incorrect guess at the solution of the "shells" puzzle, not by something in the comments there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Final Answer**

> we have to add same letters at the front and back of the words. Hence, the reference to the Shells puzzle. Doing this with the given words, we get:
>  ChiC, AreA(in comments), RadaR, RoaR, OreganO, TerrorisT(in comments), SasS, TinT, EscapE, WheW. These letters possibly combine to give the name of a food product. Hence, the stego tag.
> The letters give CARROTSTEW. So, our answer is CARROT STEW! Tasty dinner.

Comment: YES. You're very much on the right track. Keep looking (and remember that the telegram service has made some spacing errors).

Comment: Ohio, area, greg, prep could also work for the first two.

Comment: @Apep Hm, Area sounds more plausible than Oreo. Ohio and Greg are Proper nouns, though. Don't think that counts.

Answer (score -1):

I guess wildly, it could be

> a Nescafe product (suitable for dinner!)

as,

> the last two words "...in scaphe" sound 'Nescafe' if heard not carefully !

Comment: Not sure... considering the first bit is 'hi reader' split up then I'd sort of expect that to be continued throughout. Especially with the comment - it points towards mussel/muscle homophone

Comment: Nope, sorry. The answer is much clearer than this once you find it, and should be uniquely enough derivable from the puzzle to be pretty much self-confirming.

Comment: My above comment also applies to the edited answer :-)

Comment: Try actually solving the puzzle instead of making wild guesses based on limited information.